# Disable redirects symfony security

Tags: security, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.5 i have setup a basic simple_form and i have secured a /admin path, if i try to to to /admin/panel for example always i get redirects to /login, i dont want the redirects i want a 401 response

here is my conf

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
        provider: my_user_provider
        simple_form:
            authenticator: form.authenticator
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/   , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: add a path to login_path that returns 401 code

Comment: use Request class and its setStatusCode(integer $code, mixed $text = null)
method

Comment: There is a option in `firewalls:` `access_denied_url:` that you can provide url or a route name.

Answer (score 4):

I solved adding a `entry_point: my_entry_point` to my security

```
// declared like service 'my_entry_point'
class MyEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $response = new Response("", Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);

        return $response;
    }
}
```